# <Azure Custom Vision>Training images cannot be uploaded

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I can’t upload training images when the number of uploaded files reaches `1066`. Would you please teach me if you know how to deal with it?

- Error message: `images were not uploaded because you ran out of 'quota'. See quotas in Setting`.
- I changed the plan from `F0` to `S0` , butit did not resolve.
- Looks like the quota limit has not been reached.

[image: Quota capture]

Comment: How are you uploading the images? It can be a "Transaction per second" quota also. Regarding the plan change, could you try to directly create a new project now that you have S0, and import again?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I realised my training image have problem. The classification type of this project is multiclass, but I will add 2 tag to same  image unintentionally.It seemed to be the cause. I was uploading traning images for identify types of penguins, but an image that was already uploaded to the King Penguin tag was mixed in the images that I tried to upload as the emperor penguin tag.